# Static readonly variable not initialized in DLL

Tags: c#, dll, static, initialization

I have a DLL that I'm trying to use in another program. This is the part that causes some issues:

**From my dll:**

```
public class fService
{
    public static readonly string connectionString = "My connection string";
    ...
    etc
    ...
    public static void myStaticMethod()
    {
        fStat x = new fStat();
    }
}
```

**From my other program:**

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        fService.myStaticMethod();
        MessageBox.Show("Success!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The exception I get is `The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.`.

Why is this? How do I initialize it properly? will the class fService have to be made static (I'd like to avoid that)?

**StackTrace:**

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at fManager.tableClasses.fStats..ctor() in e:\fManager\project\fManager\ConsoleApplication1\tableClasses\fStats.cs:line 55
   at fManager.fService.constructElement(String header, String content, fService& service) in e:\fManager\project\fManager\ConsoleApplication1\fService.cs:line 964
   at fManager.fService.LoadIni(String path) in e:\fManager\project\fManager\ConsoleApplication1\fService.cs:line 675
   at fManagerF.mainForm.btnSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\fManager\exeProject\fManagerF\fManager\mainForm.cs:line 54
```

**and this is where the problem seem to originate:**

```
public fStat()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("fManager.getfStats", conn);
        SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [fManager].[fStats]", conn);
        _id = 0;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        conn.Open();
        _id = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** If you downvote/vote to close, please tell me why. I feel like I've provided all the info and I stay on topid, but please help me improve by letting me know where I failed =)

Comment: Show the code for `//this is where the connectionString is used.` and the actual stack trace. The error you're getting is _not_ an error thrown by the .NET runtime talking about your `connectionString` member, but some database connection code.

Comment: show the stacktrace . The code looks correct !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define your `connectionString` property as static member of `fService` class but you use a varible `connectionString` in `fStat` class. That's not the same variable. Your `fService.connectionString` is initzialized, your `fStat.connectionString` is not. So also the `ConnectionString` in your `SqlConnection` is not initialized, thus the error.

Comment: such a beginner thing to miss, I feel embarrased ^^ anyway, thanks for the help!